# Android Firebase get single value as string

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this problem, that I cannot get single value from my firebase json and check it if it is null or not.

Here is my json file:

```
{ "117500978158564407389": 
   {
    "uid" : "117500978158564407389",
    "cat_list" : {
    "category_list" : [ {
      "cat_name" : "Work"
    }, {
      "cat_name" : "Health"
    }, {
      "cat_name" : "Food"
    }, {
      "cat_name" : "Spare time"
    }, {
      "cat_name" : "Travel"
    } ]
    }
    }
    }
```

Here is my code in Presenter of MVP where i try to get value of my "uid" in json. But it always shows a null.

```
@Override
public String getId(String id) {     
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://talisproject-89e62.firebaseio.com/userData/");
    reference.child("117500978158564407389").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            CategoryList categoryList = dataSnapshot.getValue(CategoryList.class);
            ID = categoryList.getUid();

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return ID;
}
}
```

Here is my POJO class

```
public class CategoryList implements Serializable {
public List<Category> categoryList;


public List<Category> getCategoryList() {
    return categoryList;
}

public void setCategoryList(List<Category> categoryList) {
    this.categoryList = categoryList;
}

public CategoryList catList;
public String uid;

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}

public CategoryList(CategoryList catList, String uid) {

    this.catList = catList;
    this.uid = uid;
}

}
```

And Here where I call my Presenter function, it always shows a *null*. Does anyone knows, why it always shows a null and how can I get this value?

```
ID = interPresenter.getId(uid);
```

Comment: *Does anyone knows, why it always shows a null* ... I know ... firebase is async http://ideone.com/PPHi95 ... obviously `return ID;` appear before  listener hits `onDataChange`

Answer (score 2):

Firebase doesn't get the data immediately, obviously... It needs to download data.

`onDataChange` is called when the data is downloaded. When you did `return ID`, ID is `null` since `onDataChange` hasn't been called yet. It's simply logic.

See [How to return the value from inner class to outer class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33120745/how-to-return-the-value-from-inner-class-to-outer-class)